# Installer hangs with JRE 8

Tags: install4j

We've recently moved our install4j project to use JRE 8. However the installer hangs at a specific dialog and we see the following in error.log. Would you know what could be causing this?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.text.BreakIterator.createBreakInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.BreakIterator.getBreakInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getBreakSpotUseBreakIterator(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getBreakSpot(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getBreakWeight(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.FlowView$LogicalView.getPreferredSpan(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.FlowView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.getMinimumSpan(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSpanOnAxis(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.layout(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.setSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.validateView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.scrollRectToVisible(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.scrollRectToVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.InfoScreen.updateText(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.InfoScreen.willActivate(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.ScreenEnvelope.activate(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.WizardBase.setScreen(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.WizardScreenExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the hot spot compiler in Java 8, see

http://kingsfleet.blogspot.co.il/2014/11/but-thats-impossible-or-finding-out.html

According to the above blog post, a workaround is to add the following VM parameter

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot
```